# exit block of code with express and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my code

```
// on all routes that end with "users", do the following
router.route('/users')
    .post(function(req, res, next) {

        var user = new User();
        user.username = req.body.username;
        user.password = req.body.password;

        User.find({username : user.username}, function(err, results){
            if (results.length > 0) {

                //if (err) res.send(err);
                console.log('User exists: ', user.username);
                res.send('User exists');
                next();
            }

        });

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({
                message: 'Created user.',
                username: req.body.username,
                password: req.body.password
            });
        });

    })
```

`User` is just a Mongoose schema.

If the username is found in that first callback, I want to send a basic response of "User Exists", then exit. Right now I get an error because it moves on to the `user.save` bit and tries to write more info to the response which has already ended.

How can I exit the `User.find` block and the `.post` block altogether? In a normal C-like language I'd simply do `return;` but doing so only exits just the `User.find` block.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write another case in `else` condition and return the callback like this

```
 router.route('/users')
.post(function(req, res, next) {

    var user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;

    User.find({username : user.username}, function(err, results){
        if (results.length > 0) {

            //if (err) res.send(err);
            console.log('User exists: ', user.username);
            res.send('User exists');
             return next();
        }else{
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    return res.send(err);

                return res.json({
                    message: 'Created user.',
                    username: req.body.username,
                    password: req.body.password
                });
            });
        }

    });

})
```

Comment: I think one other thing that should be fixed is that you don't call `next()` after `res.send()`.  In fact `next()` is meant to signify that you want other route handlers to continue to process this route which is not what should happen when you've sent the response.

Comment: Yes, @jfriend00 it can be, I am updating the answer

Comment: Thank you, this should do it. Just for the future, is there a way to exit all the way up through a chain of callbacks or do you just need to code a bit smarter like you suggested in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, if it finds the user, it will run whatever you have written in your callback. You happen to have `next()` inside your callback. `next()` will exit this route and find the next route that would match. That means whatever you wrote under, won't be executed (I'm talking about the `user.save` part.

Anyways, to answer your question, if you want it to exit the `User.find` block and the `.post` all together, then just put the `next()` method below and outside your `if` statement.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that wouldn't work outside of the "if" because then if no current users with that username are found it would not move on to the username creation. It would hit the "next" then skip over the save block.